# how can i show a report when I click a button in java program using netbeans plugin IReport

Tags: java, database, report

I am creating a program that will show the data inside the table of a database, I use IReport plugin for netbeans to create a report for that. I want to call that report when i click the a button . but it gives me this error,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:65)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:99)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:95)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<init>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:72)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<clinit>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:60)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getDefaultInstance(JasperCompileManager.java:83)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:448)
at RecordManagementSystem.connection$thehandler.actionPerformed(connection.java:270)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 44 more
```

I think this is the part where i get my errors :

```
   if(event.getSource()==show){
       try{  
           String path = "C:\\NetBeansProjects\\SADSIGN\\src\\RecordManagementSystem\\report2.jrxml";                 
          JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
          JasperPrint jp =  JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,con);
          JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
          }catch(Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, save);
             }
                 }
```

here is my whole code :

```
  import java.sql.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import net.sf.jasperreports.view.*;
  import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;

  public class connection extends JFrame {

     Connection con;
     Statement st;
     ResultSet rs;

    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JTextField t3;
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;
    private JButton ud;
    private JButton del;
    private JButton nw;
    private JButton save;

            private JButton show;

    public connection(){        
        connect();
        createFrame();
    }

    public void connect(){
        try{    
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            String connect = "jdbc:odbc:RIM";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connect);

            st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            String sql = "select * from test";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        }catch(Exception e){}   
    }

    public void createFrame(){
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(480,200);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        JLabel first = new JLabel("First name");
        first.setBounds(40, 11, 75, 14);
        getContentPane().add(first);

        t1 = new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(102, 8, 108, 20);
        getContentPane().add(t1);
        t1.setColumns(10);

        JLabel last = new JLabel("Last Name");
        last.setBounds(220, 11, 75, 14);
        getContentPane().add(last);

        t2 = new JTextField();
        t2.setBounds(288, 8, 100, 20);
        getContentPane().add(t2);
        t2.setColumns(10);

        JLabel age = new JLabel("Age");
        age.setBounds(138, 39, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(age);

        t3 = new JTextField();
        t3.setBounds(187, 39, 108, 20);
        getContentPane().add(t3);
        t3.setColumns(10);

        b1 = new JButton("next");
        b1.setBounds(40, 78, 75, 23);
        getContentPane().add(b1);

        b2 = new JButton("prev");
        b2.setBounds(123, 78, 75, 23);
        getContentPane().add(b2);   

        b3 = new JButton("last\r\n");
        b3.setBounds(208, 78, 75, 23);
        getContentPane().add(b3);

        b4 = new JButton("first");
        b4.setBounds(299, 78, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(b4);

        ud = new JButton("Update");
        ud.setBounds(26, 123, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(ud);

        del = new JButton("Delete");
        del.setBounds(123, 123, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(del);

        nw = new JButton("New");
        nw.setBounds(225, 123, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(nw);

                    show = new JButton("show");
                    show.setBounds(400,123,89,23);
                    getContentPane().add(show);

        save = new JButton("save");
        save.setBounds(324, 123, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(save);

        try{
            rs.next();
            t1.setText(rs.getString("Fname"));
            t2.setText(rs.getString("Lname"));
            t3.setText(rs.getString("Age"));


        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        thehandler handler = new thehandler();
        b1.addActionListener(handler);
        b2.addActionListener(handler);
        b3.addActionListener(handler);
        b4.addActionListener(handler);
        ud.addActionListener(handler);
        del.addActionListener(handler);
        nw.addActionListener(handler);
        save.addActionListener(handler);
                    show.addActionListener(handler);
            }






private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                if(event.getSource()==b1){
                    try{    
                        if(rs.next()){
                            t1.setText(rs.getString("fname"));
                            t2.setText(rs.getString("lname"));
                            t3.setText(rs.getString("age"));        

                        }else{

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more records");
                            rs.previous();
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }

                if(event.getSource()==b2){
                    try{                        
                        if(rs.previous()){
                            t1.setText(rs.getString("fname"));
                            t2.setText(rs.getString("lname"));
                            t3.setText(rs.getString("age"));        

                        }else{

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more records");
                            rs.next();
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }

                if(event.getSource()==b3){
                    try{
                        rs.last();
                        t1.setText(rs.getString("fname"));
                        t2.setText(rs.getString("lname"));
                        t3.setText(rs.getString("age"));
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }
                if(event.getSource()==b4){
                    try{
                        rs.first();
                        t1.setText(rs.getString("fname"));
                        t2.setText(rs.getString("lname"));
                        t3.setText(rs.getString("age"));

                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }
                if(event.getSource()==ud){
                    String fname = t1.getText();
                    String lname = t2.getText();
                    String age = t3.getText();

                    try{
                        rs.updateString("fname", fname);
                        rs.updateString("lname", lname);
                        rs.updateString("age", age);                
                        rs.updateRow();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record updated successfully");
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }

                if(event.getSource()==del){
                    try{
                        rs.deleteRow();

                        t1.setText("");
                        t2.setText("");
                        t3.setText("");



                        if(rs.last()){
                            rs.previous();
                            t1.setText(rs.getString("fname"));
                            t2.setText(rs.getString("lname"));
                            t3.setText(rs.getString("age"));


                        }else if(rs.first()){
                        rs.next();
                        t1.setText(rs.getString("fname"));
                        t2.setText(rs.getString("lname"));
                        t3.setText(rs.getString("age"));
                        }


                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }

                if(event.getSource()==nw){
                    t1.setText(" ");
                    t2.setText(" ");
                    t3.setText(" ");
                }

                if(event.getSource()==save){
                    String lname = t1.getText();
                    String fname = t2.getText();
                    String age = t3.getText();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Successfully added");


                    try{
                        rs.moveToInsertRow();

                        rs.updateString("fname", lname);
                        rs.updateString("lname", fname);
                        rs.updateString("age", age);
                        rs.insertRow();

                        rs.next();

                        t1.setText(rs.getString("fname"));
                        t2.setText(rs.getString("lname"));
                        t3.setText(rs.getString("age"));

                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }

                                if(event.getSource()==show){
                                 try{   
                                    String path = "C:\\NetBeansProjects\\SADSIGN\\src\\RecordManagementSystem\\report2.jrxml";                    
                                    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
                                    JasperPrint jp =  JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,con);
                                    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
                                 }catch(Exception e){
                                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, save);
                                 }
                                }
            }
        }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new connection();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the results of `System.getproperty("java.classpath");` and also post the location of where your JDK is? If you are using a Windows machine, you might try looking in `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin`. If the location does not match what was printed by the `println()`, Google **Set Classpath Java** and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Inventari",null);  

    JasperDesign jd  = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\RrezartP\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Inventari\\src\\Report\\Mjetethemelore.jrxml");
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\RrezartP\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Inventari\\src\\Report\\Mjetethemelore.jrxml");
    JasperPrint  jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, new HashMap(),con);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(
    jp, "C:\\PDF Raportet\\MjeteReport.pdf");


}

catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that LogFactory Class is missing, Please check your web-inf/lib folder and check if there org.apache.commons.looging.LogFactory class present or not, also check it in your build path. If not then download the required jar and add to your build path.